# Query in SQLite on PhoneGap with Ñ character (latin) dont give results

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, character-encoding

I use PhoneGap for develop an application. I use Ripple to test in a browser my develop, and then I test my App in real Device.

I have a lot of rows with latin Characters, like Ñ, Ü, etc, and my app on Android device show perfectly this characters when I make a query that dont have this characters.

For instance, the row have

```
NAME              ADDRESS
PETER NUÑEZ       RUE DES AMIES,16, 4AC3
```

If i make a Query:

`var word='AMIES';`

`...select * from table where ADDRESS like '%?%',[word]...`

it works fine and give me the row perfectly, but if I try:

`var word='NUÑEZ';`

`...select * from table where NAME like '%?%',[word]...`

it doesn't give result.

And If I use: `var word='NU%EZ';` it works fine.

I use SQL injection for make the Queries `..(,?,[var])..`

What is the problem? I can show Ñ, Ü, etc. characters retrieved from Query, but I can not query anything with those latin characters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Has your db this value 'PRAGMA encoding = "UTF-8";'?

Comment: Where I set this value? I use phonegap, have I execute this sentence before queries?

Comment: It's a statement and if you set it one time that value should be there forever. Here's the documentation about it: http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html

Comment: Well, I try it. Firstly I test PRAGMA encoding and I will see what's the encoding.

Comment: Hi Again, I try it, but when I execute sentence in PhoneGap (Javascript), it give me this: `could not prepare statement (23 not authorized)`

Comment: That PRAGMA is not necessary.

Comment: `'%?%'` does not work. Please show the code with the actual query.

Answer (score 0):

using apache cordova, in my start page "www\index.html" adding `<meta charset="utf-8" />` to head works fine for me :3.